# How to tell systemd a java process has exited but restarted itself with a new pid?

Tags: debian, systemd, java

I set up a systemd service for a java application. Everything is working fine until the java application restarts itself. While restarting, the main java process that is observed by systemd exits with status 0 and launches a new instance of itself. Systemd now thinks that the process exited.

How can I tell systemd the new PID of the process launched by the restarting java application?

How do I even get the PID of the newly launched process?

The systemd service is defines as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyJavaApp
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=myuser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar -Djava.awt.headless=true /opt/MyJavaApp/MyJavaApp.jar &
ExecStop=/usr/bin/java -jar -Djava.awt.headless=true /opt/MyJavaApp/MyJavaApp.jar -quit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What do you mean by restarting? Is parent restarting or one of the children? Do you create any forks on your own with your Java application?

Comment: pstree before the restart: `bash(18822)───java(23842)` pstree after the restart `java(24867)`. Sadly I don't have the source code of the java application. @KamilBoratyński What information do you need?

Comment: Ach! See the mistake. I am anwering in the, wait a second.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't. With `type=simple`, systemd tracks the process directly executed by the `ExecStart` parameter. Though `type=forking` would still have a similar issue, in that systemd would track the process, and as soon as it exits, systemd will think it's dead.

The difficulty with this is that systemd has no way of knowing that this is what your application's normal behavior is. It could be that your application has a master process, and then spawns of child worker processes. And so systemd would think that your master has died, and left some children around that need to be cleaned up.

There are 2 ways you could solve this:

1. Somehow create a monitor process that systemd executes, and this process launches your application. Then somehow have this monitor process be able to tell the difference between the application exiting, vs fork-exit. This can be rather difficult to implement as it's not easy to keep track of a child processes' children.
   One way that might work would be to create an anonymous pipe, pass the write end of the pipe to the process, and wait for EOF on the read end of it. As long as your application doesn't close unknown file descriptors it should work.
2. Change your application to use `exec` instead of `fork`+`exec`. This way the new process uses the same PID as the old process.